# How to use Capybara to match dynamic image file names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have been trying to use Capybara to match actual image file name with expected file name.

I have images that are stored in `app/assets/images`, e.g. `image01.png`.

The file name of these images are stored in the `image_file_name` field of one or more tables.

They are being rendered using `<%= @object.image_file_name %>` in one of more `html.erb` file. However, the actual file name rendered has a series of alphanumeric characters at the right hand side, e.g. `assets/image01-d4f7d162a9ecb8877e69bc96a8ca03bd7531c8faf7be7c65ba60c14e7c6fe530.png'`.

I've tried the following expectations and they work:

```
expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='image01-d4f7d162a9ecb8877e69bc96a8ca03bd7531c8faf7be7c65ba60c14e7c6fe530.png']")
expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='image01']")
```

May I know is there a way to validate that the image file name starts with `image01` and ends with `.png` regardless of what are in between? If that couldn't be achieved with `hav_css`, how about `have_selector` or `have_xpath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply multiple CSS attribute selectors to the same field so

```
expect(page).to have_css(“img[src^=‘image01’][src$=‘.png’]”)
```

should do what you want

Comment: Since the ```src``` actually contains the directory name ```assets/```, I have adapted the suggested answer as follows, and it works: ```expect(page).to have_css("img[src^='assets/image01'][src$='.png']")```